# software based captive portal for wide area

Tags: iptables, wifi, captive-portal

I'm trying to organise some wide wifi network

imagine a small town with several wifi points

when user is connected to a wifi point, device is redirected to captive-portal(cp) website where they must input some info and accept terms and condtitions

we organised captive portal behind each wifi-point with linux iptables (allowing users to go to internet if device with their mac address accepted terms of service)

[image: schema]

it works perfect until user moves to another location(to other wifi point) - user have to accept-terms again on captive portal

we created a sync of the list of mac addresses between capive portals to avoid that issue, but then comes other issue since amount of internet users is about 90000 - we have high CPU load on CP machines because iptables handling that 90k+ mac address rules

so the question - is there some lightweght solution like iptables filtering by mac-address or maybe we should use some other strategy ?

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a central RADIUS server for authentication. It will keep a list of valid (and logged-in) users/devices and can inform the access points about the status of a device, which then needs to manage only currently connected devices.

Another approach, which can also be combined with the RADIUS solution, is to have a  central, powerful gateway where the access points connect to that handles all the routing/firewall stuff. Naturally, this requires a network architecture supporting this kind of topology.